# Adding image to the TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

im trying to add an icon to my username textfield, somehow I added the icon but I cant add any padding to it.

What I mean is, I want it to look like this:
[image]

And what I get is this:
[image]

```
let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()


        let imageView = UIImageView()

        let image = UIImage(named: "user-icon")

        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 15)
        tf.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        tf.leftView = imageView
        tf.addSubview(imageView)


        var placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray])
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 34, green: 34, blue: 34)
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        tf.textColor = .white
        tf.layer.borderWidth = 1
        tf.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.1).cgColor
        tf.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return tf
    }()
```

And this is my code block. Even if I change the x and y values it doesnt event move any pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the width of the view and center the image. Adjust the width accordingly (I have set it 50). Try this ...

```
let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()


        let imageView = UIImageView()

        let image = UIImage(named: "user-icon")

        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 15)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        tf.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        tf.leftView = imageView
        tf.addSubview(imageView)


        var placeholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray])
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 35.0/100.0, green: 34.0/100.0, blue: 34.0/100.0, alpha: 1)
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        tf.textColor = .white
        tf.layer.borderWidth = 1
        tf.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.1).cgColor
        tf.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return tf
    }()
```

Comment: First of all I have got an extension for RGB so I dont need to use /255. And isnt there any way to give a spesific padding? Like 5px left, 10px right. Because increasing width may be useful for this time in another case I may need more powerfull staff.

Comment: ah okay.. no there isn't any padding.. another options is to add transparent area in your image on left and right sides.

Comment: Uhm im struggling on different issues many hours so my brain doesnt work right now >_> can you give me an example about adding transparent area

Comment: i mean you are using `user-icon` which i suppose is 10x15 .. Alternatively use an image of resolution '50x15' by adding transparent area on left and right sides of your actual image.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified some changes and its done.